# clang-tooling applyAllReplacements won't work

Tags: c++, clang

I'm trying to replace some types, `double` to `float` for example, on the AST using clang::tooling::RefactoringTool::applyAllReplacement().

I have a class A in which I have a clang::tooling::RefactoringTool `tool`, and in which I create some matcher that match for example a varDecl :
`double var =`

It also has a Class B attribute that inherits from MatchFinder::MatchCallback which does the callback when there is a match result, and it saves to A the filename, offset and length of the type `double` to then create a replacement using this `Replacement(StringRef FilePath, unsigned Offset, unsigned Length, StringRef ReplacementText)`.
All this part works well, but then I try to apply the replacements like this:

```
DiagnosticsEngine diags(nullptr, nullptr);
SourceManager SM(diags, tool->getFiles());
Rewriter rewrite = Rewriter(SM, clang::LangOptions());
tool->applyAllReplacements(rewrite);
```

But the applyAllReplacements returns false.

I'm not sure why it doesn't work, maybe I can't just construct a SourceManager and a Rewriter like that ?